# How to call function that counts digits in an integer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

My function should get a non-negative integer, and return how many digits there are in the number, for Example for the number 563 the function return 3. 
And for 0 will return 1.

*I'm new in c so it still very confusing for me.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numOfDigits(int n); //Declartion

void main()
{
    int num1, counter = 0, newNum;

    printf("Enter A Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
}

int numOfDigits(int n1)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (n1 == 0)
        return 1;

    while (n1 > 0) {
        counter++;
        n1 /= 10;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

What should I write to make the program work?

Comment: "What should i write to make the program work?" You forgot to explain why/how it doesn't work.

Comment: `main()` should call `numOfDigits()`.

Comment: . . . and print its result.

Comment: How can I call the function and pass to main?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the section of your textbook that explains how to call functions. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics.

Comment: Your `main` function is missing the line `printf("Number of digits = %d\n", numOfDigits(num1));`. The code has other problems too : it won't work with negative numbers, or when you enter `banana` and so on. It is no use *hoping* the user will enter what you expect: you must catch input faults.

Comment: What is the largest number code must handle?

Comment: How about using log10?

Comment: How about using log10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the digit counting function that you made and assign its return value to a variable, and then print the value of that variable using `printf()` function; or alternatively, call your digit counting function inside `printf()` as an argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numOfDigits(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Enter A Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    counter = numOfDigits(num1);
    printf("number of digits: %d\n", counter);

    //printf("number of digits: %d\n", numOfDigits(num1)); alternate method

}

int numOfDigits(int n1)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (n1 == 0)
        return 1;

    while (n1 > 0) {
        counter++;
        n1 /= 10;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

A couple of notes:

- Since you mentioned that you need to get a non-negative number, consider using `unsigned int` type, and change the format specifier inside `scanf()` and `printf()` call to `"%u"`.
- Function `main` should be declared as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Thank you machine_1!  I understand now how it works.   What is the purpose of the return 1 in this code?  i know what the number is equal to zero it should return 1  but what it really means?

Comment: @AndrewM It means, if the number passed to the function is `0`, then  `1` is returned because `0` is a single digit.

Comment: @AndrewM Click on the check mark beside the answer, to the left.